# How to get a vertical Slice in a Swift 3 multi-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a simple two-dimensional array in Swift 3, like so:

```
let myData = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
```

What I would like to be able to get is a simple Slice that represented a vertical column, so for example slicing the first column would give me an ArraySlice that has the contents `[1, 3]`.

I was hoping to be able to use some simple syntax to generate a Slice across the array like so:

```
let sliceCol = myData[0...1][0]
```

or

```
let sliceRow = myData[0][0...1]
```

but both lines of code evaluate to a slice which is just one of the rows (result is `[1, 2]` in both cases).

Searching around yields a lot of results with Swift arrays that are flat, but there don't seem to be very many examples using multi-dimensional arrays in Swift.  I can simply loop through the array and build up a new array with just the given column entries but I was thinking there had to be an efficient way to get a slice from a multi-dimensional array in Swift 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a two-dimensional array. This is an array of arrays. Sometimes people try to treat that as a 2D array, but it's really quite different. For example, each row does not have to have the same number of elements. Mutating these data structures in Swift tends to be very expensive due to copy-on-write behaviors. As you've seen, even accessing it can be very inefficient. stdlib doesn't include a real multi-dimensional array.

If you are doing things that require real two-dimensional arrays, you're going to want a data structure for that. For small matrices, I suggest looking at GLKit, which includes 3x3 and 4x4 matrices of Floats. You can also look at `simd` which includes a number of matrix types.

If your needs are more general than that, you'll really want to build a custom `Matrix` type. There are many [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=%5Bswift%5D+matrix&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93). If you're serious about this, you probably want to look for something that maintains its own copy-on-write backing store and doesn't use a `[[T]]` internally.

Comment: That is a great point that it's an array of arrays, and not really a multi-dimensional array in the classic sense, I guess I was just hoping Swift had some syntactic shortcut for this case  - for now a custom Matrix class is probably overkill for what I need, but I may consider incorporating something like that if access gets out of hand. Thanks!

Comment: So this is a semi related question for anyone: Why isn't there a Numpy like library in Swift, or pandas like DataFrames? Would it make much difference in matrix algebra computation time?